# Scrapy item from recursive requests

Tags: scrapy

I need create only one item from recursive multiple pages:

Page A / Page B relationship: 1 to N
Page B / Page C relationship: 1 to N
And result item is:

```
{
  A_1, 
  A_2, 
  A_3,
  [
    {
       B_1, 
       B_2,
       [
         {C_1, C_2},
         {C_1, C_2}
       ]
    },
    {
       B_1, 
       B_2,
       [
          {C_1, C_2},
          {C_1, C_2} 
       ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

I tried to use [inline_requests](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-inline-requests/) but only works on the first level